# -walletnotify on 6 confirmations instead of 1?

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoind, confirmations, wallet-notify

Pretty straight forward. Right now im using -walletnotify to run some node.js code when i get an incoming transaction and when theres 1 confirmation. However, after reading around, i found out that 1 confirmation is not secure, which now makes me want to execute this confirmation code when theres at least 6 confirmations.

**TL;DR**, Is there a parameter or an equivalent for -walletnotify to run on N confirmations?

Comment: Maybe you can use -txconfirmtarget ?

Comment: Not out of the box with core.

Comment: I had opened issue - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/10021 on bitcoin github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of Bitcoin-Core (0.13.1).

Consider opening a issue (feature request) https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin or start implementing it yourself.